# Movie about a young boy who get's sucked into his antenna and so transporting him into his tv or some parallel world

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

It's a movie that I use to love when I was little but I never knew the title and barely remember what happens in it anymore.

The movie is from the **80'-90's**, and I believe it pretty much starts with the boy buying a new bicycle and when he gets home he leaves it outside, but the next day he doesn't find it there.

He starts wondering where it went or how it disappeared. Eventually, more things in his house start being sucked on through his big antenna in the front yard of his house. At some point there was this huge wind (or some kind of gravitation) pulling him towards the antenna and he had to hold on to one of the columns in his porch but now his feet were hanging in the direction of the antenna. I think eventually the antenna sucked him in. Then, I believe, he got transported inside the tv (or some kind of parallel universe)

Now, what I'm about to say, I'm not sure if it's also from this movie or I'm confusing it with another one.

But what happened is, his parents were also missing (I think he thought they were sucked by the antenna and he had to go in to rescue them). At some point he is in this store at the mall or something like that and time is running out to find his parents. He sees them far away and he starts running as fast as he can to get to them. But I don't remember what happens after that.

Comment: Having your bike and your parents sucked by a satellite dish into a TV realm is pretty much [Stay Tuned](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6X55pBl4fQ) from 1992.

Comment: Oh yeah, I just checked the trailer and it is. Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

This is Peter Hyams' comedy [Stay Tuned](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105466/combined) from 1992.

> A husband and wife are sucked into a hellish TV and have to survive a gauntlet of twisted versions of TV shows they find themselves in.

They get a mysterious satellite dish that sucks them in and also sucks their kid's bike at some point. Stars John Ritter as the dad and features animation by Chuck Jones. Here's the trailer: